# Getting 500 Server Error with Spring Boot REST application JpaRepository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-restcontroller

I am working on a Spring Boot based application that exposes its database through REST by using a number of interfaces extending JpaRepository. Everything looks and works fine with the exception of a curious phenomenon:
When I POST to create a new row in the database, it does its job well. The row gets created in the table. Even my aspect around "*save()" method gets triggered and all. Despite all the positive outlook, the response code is 500.
Please advice on how I can dig into that?

Comment: 500 error code suggests your code threw exception on the server. What was the exception?

Comment: No exceptions in the log. All smooth. Actually I don't even have any "code". I just declare the interface and Spring automatically supplies the implementation.

Comment: There is an exception somewhere. It may not be logged if you have custom error handling, but it is there somewhere. Post some code at least. If possible create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If it wasnt code, it would be configuration. So provide that config.  If you cant provide either, this is not a good forum to ask such question. Remember SO is all about code.

Comment: My question is initially about finding about if someone could suggest anything to debug, or log in detail so I could potentially work it out by myself.
I understand that this is not the case and therefore I will work on an mvce asap. Many thanks so far.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it. It is the "around" aspect which does not return the result returned by the `joinPoint.proceed()`

It was like that:

```
@Around("execution(* save(..))")
void saveWithNotify(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable
{
    Object entity = joinPoint.proceed();
    afterSave(entity);
}
```

Corrected as:

```
@Around("execution(* save(..))")
Object saveWithNotify(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable
{
    Object entity = joinPoint.proceed();
    afterSave(entity);
    return entity;
}
```

Many thanks to those who tried to help

Comment: Still, I need to understand/check why it did not rollback the transaction.